# Auth with ssh key only

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm currently working on something on my lab, i want to deploy script to let users auth with ssh key only through ssh and rotate those key every 90 days

Those users need to have root rights on the machine

After some scripts writing i got the things

But something disturb me, to allow user to become root after ssh auth with key i need to put NOPASSWD arg on my sudoers file for those users

In a security point of view is it acceptable or not ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to use NOPASSWD because you have removed the unix password for these users?
If so, a different approach is to make use of `Match User` and `AuthenticationMethods` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

```
Match User foobar
    AuthenticationMethods publickey
```

This should disable everything but publickey as login method for user foobar, while still allowing console login with password, and thus sudo with password.